# modify Readonly Tuple in flask-alchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following scenario

```
partner = query().filter(Partners.id == partner_id).first()
if partner != None:
    partner.config = json.loads(partner.config, cls=DateTimeDecoder)
```

I want to modify the the response of sqlalchemy query result.
But as it's a Readonly tuple, its not allowing me to do so.

Can somebody tell me how to do this ?

Basically after the processing if I want to get partner.config, I should get the proper value.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert it into `list` and then you can change data in list.

ResultSet return from query will be immutable so you cant change directly same object.